# Return value from async function from its parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm working on a build provider for the Atom text editor, which is a component based on the [`build`](https://github.com/noseglid/atom-build) package. This package allows you to run some tests to check whether a provider is eligible to run or not, returning `true` or `false` respectively.

I'm using [`glob`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) to check whether a certain file-type is present in the project folder to determine whether to activate the build provider. For example, a project folder should include a LESS file in order to activate a build provider for `lessc`.

**Example:**

```
isEligible() {
    const paths = glob.sync("**/*.less");

    if (paths.length > 0) {
      // one or more LESS files found
      return true;
    }    

    // no LESS files found
    return false;
}
```

I'm wondering if the same is possible using `glob` asynchronously, specifically how I can return the state from `isEligible()`. The following does *not* work:

```
isEligible() {
    return glob("**/*.less", function (err, files) {
      if (err) {
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    })
}
```

Comment: You can't ! You could do  `isEligible().then( (data) => {})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following does not work

Yes. It [absolutely cannot work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572).

If the caller of `isEligible` (i.e. the `build` package) does not support asynchrony, then you have to make your function synchronous, there is no way around it. You might file a feature request for providing a callback to `isEligible` or accepting a promise as the return value, though.

Comment: That explains why my previous attemps, similar to AJS's answer, don't work. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

As the function is executing asynchronously return statement won't work instead what you need to do is use callback ie:

```
isEligible(callback) {
    glob("**/*.less", function (err, files) {
      if (err) {
        return false;
      }

      callback(true);
    })
}
```

**Usage**

```
//call isEligible

isEligible(function(result){
   //do something with result
});
```